# Unable to retrieve image blob with encoded & (ampersand) in SAS part of url

Tags: html, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, url-encoding

I have image blob url in following form:
https://my-storage.blob.core.windows.net/my-container/my-virtual-directory/image-name.png?sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&si=my-policy&sig=ZiKivSYXr63vBtdY7IsxVQ01WmrFnK%2FC9xABVrho6sY%3D&se=2016-10-04T15%3A37%3A11Z

I use this image source in my html editor inside tag .
Problem is when url get encoded & is replaced with & and after my image is not available from that url. I tried doing it inside browser directly (replacing any & to &) and it returns response "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."

Why is this happening? What might be the solution?

Comment: What do you mean replacing & to &? could you provide some code snippet for introduction?

Comment: To &amp; I use summernote html editor, and on image upload src is encoded (& is replaced with &amp;) which makes image broken.

Comment: I just tried with one of the images in one of my storage account and it worked just fine. I saw that all the `&` were replaced with `&amp;` and that did not cause any problem. What happens when you take the SAS URL and directly put that in browser's address bar? Are you able to see the image in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are referring to the fact that the tool is escaping some characters and replacing with html safe characters such as `&amp;`. For more about HTML escape characters, please see [W3 doc](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes).

One thing you can do is to get the Azure URLs shortened via a URL shortener service (such as https://goo.gl/) and then place it in the HTML editor.

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue with Shared Access Storage (SAS) URI that are exported. Just add a single quote around the entire URL and (double quotes) " around the & (ampersand). This should work in powershell.